# Besides showing intent any performance benefit of "in" parameters Vs "ref"

Tags: c#, .net

When passing a plain old struct to a method by reference is there any performance benefit from using `in` vs `ref`.

When using `in`, which is effectively a "`readonly ref`", [you are introducing the possibility of unintended defensive copies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/):

> Remember I’ve mentioned that the `in` parameters are similar to the `readonly` fields? To make sure that the parameter’s value stays the same the compiler make a defensive copy of the parameter every time a method/property is used. If the struct is `readonly` then the compiler removes the defensive copy the same way as it does for `readonly` fields.
>
> It means that **you should never pass a non-readonly struct as `in` parameter**. It almost always will make the performance worse. Yes, the argument passing is cheaper, but once the parameter is used, the defensive copy will nullify the benefits or will make the performance worse.

From what I've read the only real benefit is that it clearly shows intent and that you don't need to specify it in the call. Am I missing something as it seems to me passing by `ref` is safer?

E.g.

```
void somemethod(in MyStruct data);
```

Vs

```
void somemethod(ref MyStruct data)
```

Comment: I don't know whether there is any perfromance benefit - I doubt it - but I don't see how you could possibly consider using `ref` safer. If someone - even you - comes along and modifies your code later, you might end up making changes to the argument that you shouldn't if it's declared `ref` whereas you will be prevented from doing so using `in`. The `in` keyword not only indicates intent but ensures that the compiler enforces that intent.

Comment: _"seems to me passing by ref is safer?"_ Why?, I'd also think it's just the other way around